# Maven build with Jacoco code coverage check never fails

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, junit5, jacoco

I want to configure Maven build to fail if test coverage is lower than 85%
Tried to use Jacoco plugin, but regardless of the coverage the build does not fail.

Runing tests with coverage in Idea works.

When i try to run `mvn clean verify` or `mvn test` this message appears:

```
[INFO] Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing execution data file:C:\Users\Shpot\Desktop\payneteasy\EQSP_project\target\jacoco.exec
```

What have I done wrong?

My `pom.xml`:

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <destFile>${basedir}/target/jacoco.exec</destFile>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>check</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <rule implementation="org.jacoco.maven.RuleConfiguration">
                                    <element>BUNDLE</element>
                                    <limits>
                                        <limit implementation="org.jacoco.report.check.Limit">
                                            <counter>INSTRUCTION</counter>
                                            <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                            <minimum>0.85</minimum>
                                        </limit>
                                        <limit implementation="org.jacoco.report.check.Limit">
                                            <counter>CLASS</counter>
                                            <value>MISSEDCOUNT</value>
                                            <maximum>0</maximum>
                                        </limit>
                                    </limits>
                                </rule>
                            </rules>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

My JUnit5 tests are like that:

```
package pne;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class CcsrchTest {

    @Test
    void hideCreditCardInformationInText() {
     ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest to remove the configuration part for `default-prepare-agent`...part... and keep the defaults which are defined by the plugin...

Comment: @khmarbaise Thanks! It worked, but build still does not fail: `[INFO] Tests are skipped.`